# How to do a custom Group By?

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

My goal is to group a data frame `DF` by values of column `Name` and aggregate specific column as sum.

### Current data frame

|  | Name | Val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Test | NaN | 5 | NaN |
| 1 | Test | 30 | NaN | 3 |
| 2 | Test | 30 | NaN | 3 |

### Output excepted

|  | Name | Val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Test | 60 | 5 | 3 |

### What I tried

```py
DF.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False)[["Val1"]].sum()
```

returns

|  | Name | Val1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Test | 60 |

### Issue

I want to take `val2` and `val3`  as unique values and then group them but I don't know how to do so.

Maybe introducing an intermediary DF

|  | Name | Val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Test | NaN | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | Test | 30 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | Test | 30 | 5 | 3 |

so that following code can work:

```
DF.groupby(['Name','val2','val3'], as_index=False)[["Val1"]].sum()
```

Keep in mind that my data frame has several values for `Name` in it.

What is the best way to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, there is only one unique non-missing value in each of the val2 and val3 columns per group. Otherwise your question does not make much sense, because you did not specify how to decide which value to take from these columns.

Given these constraints, you can use:

```
result = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).agg({'Val1': 'sum', 'val2': 'first', 'val3': 'first'})
```

Comment: @TourEiffel yes

Answer (score 0):

To group by one or multiple columns while aggregating others you can use [`groupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) followed by [`aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) (or its alias [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)).

### Example

Given input:

```
  Waiter  Revenue  Hours   Tables Gender
0  Alice     3000    3.0  Outside      f
1    Bob     2000    4.0   Inside      m
2   Alex     1000    2.0   Inside      d
3   Alex      500    0.5  Outside   None
```

Expected output:

```
        Revenue  Hours             Tables Gender
Waiter                                          
Alex       1500   1.25  {Inside, Outside}      d
Alice      3000   3.00          {Outside}      f
Bob        2000   4.00           {Inside}      m
```

Grouped by `Waiter` shows:

- the **sum** of `Revenue`
- the **mean** of worked `Hours`
- the **set** of *unique* `Tables` served
- the **first** (non undefined) value for `Gender`

### How to group-by with specific aggregation

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Waiter': ['Alice','Bob','Alex', 'Alex'], 'Revenue': [3000, 2000, 1000, 500], 'Hours': [3, 4, 2, 0.5], 'Tables': ['Outside', 'Inside', 'Inside', 'Outside'], 'Gender': ['f', 'm', 'd', None]})

df.groupby(['Waiter']).agg({'Revenue': 'sum', 'Hours': 'mean', 'Tables': lambda x: set(x), 'Gender': 'first'})
```

Explained:

1. `groupby` can be done be multiple of a single column, here only `Waiter`
2. `agg` (or `aggregate`) by a *dict* defining the aggregation for each column. The column is specified as key like `Revenue` with the *[aggregate function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function)* specified either as function name `'sum'` (in quotes or as reference like `list`) or as lambda like `lambda x: set(x)`

Note: to get the list of `Tables` we could also define following value as *aggregation function*:

- `'unique'` produces a list with unique values (see [`Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html))
- `set` for a set as we did with the lambda
- `list` for a list (which may contain duplicates)

### See also

- [pandas groupby + multiple aggregate/apply with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65440495/pandas-groupby-multiple-aggregate-apply-with-multiple-columns)
- [How to get unique values from multiple columns in a pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106490/how-to-get-unique-values-from-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-groupby)
- [How to Group By Multiple Columns in Pandas](https://datascientyst.com/use-groupby-multiple-columns-pandas/)